# How do I store persistent data on my iOS app using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, persistence

I'm developing an iOS app that is going to parse XML from an RSS feed of events and display the details of each event on a table view. Each event has a title, a description (optional), a date and a time. I am able to parse the XML data using NSXMLParser; however, I am not sure how I should store the data and make it so that it persists after the app is closed.

I have read that I can use NSCoder to persist the data but I am not sure if this is the best route forward.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions as to what I could do?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Won't you be parsing the data every time the app opens?

Comment: There are many options available, from something like https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit to writing data to the file system. Different options will require different overhead, it's kind of a broad question in that regard.

Comment: @Bawpotter I will be parsing the data every time the app opens but I would like to store all the events so that app users can view the events even when their devices are not connected to the internet.

Comment: The simplest way to store data is in persistent storage.Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231760/how-manage-user-sessions-for-unregistered-users/28235588#28235588

Comment: @Johnny I've read that NSUserDefualts is used for storing user preferences. Would you recommend it for storing a larger quantity of data?

Comment: It's not recommended that you store in the user defaults. I suggest modelling your data as objects. Also, you can take a look at [Realm](https://realm.io), it's pretty easy to use and is as robust as Core Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options for persisting data.

- `NSUserDefaults` are meant for user settings - small amounts of data. They seem unsuitable for what you have in mind.
- `NSCoding` is quite a good way to store structured data without the overhead of a database, yet it is slow [in comparison to core data](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/).
- Core Data is Apples ORM, which is quite powerfull but not as easy to wrap your head around.

I [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35517004/363777) recently, which goes into more detail regarding `NSCoding` with a complete example and some links for further reading.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jan, I will be storing at most 20 event objects. Should I focus my efforts on NSCoding? I'll read your answer to the similar question that you linked above.

Comment: @ivdekov sounds like a good choice for that amount.

Comment: do you have any recommendations for what I should do if I want to sync the data from the RSS feed with the data that I will store using NSCoding?

Comment: That depends on the feed and the data it provides. You should watch out for some sort of unique identifier. Also: If you have another question, feel free to post a question much like you posted this one:)

Comment: I am a little reluctant to post a question unless absolutely necessary because I'm trying to avoid being downvoted like I was for this question.

Comment: Read the "how to ask a question" page in the help center carefully and show you did some research on your own and you are good to go. Also, -1 isn't that bad;)

Comment: Let me be clear on that, OP: this is not all about imaginary unicorn Internet points;) if you are stuck and need help, this is the place to ask. If you play by the rules, which is asking a new question in the comments is not. Others might find that helpful too and cannot find it when searching if it is not a separate question. That's why I won't answer it here.

Comment: Thank you Jan, I'll first learn how to use NSCoding and store all the information I need and then I'll come back to StackOverflow when I get to the syncing part of my app and don't know how to do it. :)

Do you know why my question was downvoted?

Comment: By the way, the "thank you" button is right up there, called up vote;) and yes: there is documentation on the whole field of this question available from Apple that you didn't reference in your question. This is a sign of lack of research on the topic, which makes a question less good. Users tend to use their downvotes on questions rather lightly, so showing you put in some work before asking and read the relevant documentation might help you next time.

Comment: When I get some more reputation, I'll up vote your answer, thanks again for the information :)